# EXT.js Grid CheckboxSelectionModel: Header Check box not updating

Tags: extjs

I have an EXT js grid that uses the CheckboxSelectionModel. The grid is paged. The first column is check-boxes and this columns header is a check box as well. When the column header box is clicked, it selects/delesects all rows on the page, and only that page. The problem is that if on one page you select all, and then go to another, the column header box is still checked. the records are not selected which is correct, it's just the top one that is not updated. I found the code that fires when switching pages. I already have a selModel var set up. I found a condition to check whether or not the column header should be checked, I just don't know how to updated it. can anyone give me an idea how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969607/extjs-checkboxselection-header-not-updating <= you may refer to this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a listener to your grid's data store:

```
listeners : {
    'load' : function() {
       grid.getSelectionModel().clearSelections();
    }
}
```

Hopefully the `clearSelections()` method will also uncheck the header checkbox.

Comment: We use the clearSelections() and selectAll() on seperate buttons. These select/clear all records on all pages of the grid and doesn't affect the column header.